# Determine Season

Tags: code-golf, number

### Introduction:

In the **northern hemisphere** (i.e. Europe, North America, etc.), the seasons are divided like this:
- **Spring:** March, April, May
- **Summer:** June, July, August
- **Autumn:** September, October, November
- **Winter:** December, January, February

In the **southern hemisphere** however (i.e. Australia, South America, etc.), the seasons are divided like this:
- **Spring:** September, October, November
- **Summer:** December, January, February
- **Autumn:** March, April, May
- **Winter:** June, July, August

This difference is due to the position of the sun regarding the equator, where the northern and southern hemispheres have opposite seasons.

### Input:

In this challenge, we'll take two inputs:

- One for the month (`1 <= m <= 12` or `0 <= m <= 11`) (examples and test cases are all 1-indexed).
- And one for the five 'position-groups' at the latitudes of Earth (`-2 <= p <= 2`), where `-2` is the Antarctic, `-1` is the southern hemisphere excluding the Antarctic, `0` are the Tropics in proximity of the equator, `1` is the northern hemisphere excluding the Arctic, and `2` is the Arctic.
  Although the Arctic, Antarctic and Tropics of course still have seasons, for the sake of this challenge we'll say the Arctic and Antarctic are in a constant state of `Winter`, and the Tropics are in a constant state of `Summer`.

Here a visual representation of these five groups, where `-2` is the Antarctic Circle; `-1` between the Tropic of Capricorn and Antarctic Circle; `0` between the Tropic of Capricorn and Tropic of Cancer; `1` between the Arctic Circle and Tropic of Cancer; and `-2` the Arctic Circle.

[image][image]
[Source: COSMOS - The SAO Encyclopedia of Astronomy](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/)

### Output:

One of `Spring`, `Summer`, `Autumn`, or `Winter`, following these rules:

- Is the position input `2` or `-2` (Arctic or Antarctic), always output `Winter`.
- Is the position input `0` (Tropics), always output `Summer`.
- Is the position input `1` (northern hemisphere), output one of the four seasons based on the month input: `Spring` (`m = [3,5]`); `Summer` (`m = [6,8]`); `Autumn` (`m = [9,11]`); `Winter` (`m = 12 or m = [1,2]`).
- Is the position input `-1` (southern hemisphere), output one of the four seasons based on the month input: `Spring` (`m = [9,11]`); `Summer` (`m = 12 or m = [1,2]`); `Autumn` (`m = [3,5]`); `Winter` (`m = [6,8]`).

### Challenge rules:

- Output any four distinct values of your choice indicating `Spring`, `Summer`, `Autumn`, or `Winter` (please state what you've used in your answer).
  **-15 bytes bonus** if you output `Spring`, `Summer`, `Autumn`, or `Winter` as text (case-insensitive, so can be fully lowercase or fully uppercase as well, instead of the used title-case).
- Month input can be in any reasonable format. Can be either a 0-indexed or 1-indexed integer, Date-object, Month-String, etc.
- Position input will always be one of these possible five inputs `-2`, `-1`, `0`, `1`, `2`.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

### Test cases:

```
Position    1-indexed Month    Output

-2          8  (August)        Winter
-2          12 (December)      Winter
-1          3  (March)         Autumn
-1          5  (May)           Autumn
-1          8  (August)        Winter
-1          12 (December)      Summer
0           1  (January)       Summer
0           7  (July)          Summer
1           1  (January)       Winter
1           4  (April)         Spring
1           7  (July)          Summer
1           12 (December)      Winter
2           2  (February)      Winter
2           9  (September)     Winter
```

Comment: Why can't we just use four distinct values for the seasons?

Comment: I did read that rule, that's why I asked. Also, why are you afraid of "magic-integer calculations"?

Comment: I don't see anything bad with seeing only calculations, they'll be most likely used for indexing anyway. It's your challenge, but I'd say this is an unnecessary complication. EDIT: about copying, well, that's not really avoidable.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I've changed it. Any four choices are fine. -15 bytes bonus points if you output the texts. Better that way?

Comment: I don't think any bonuses are necessary, the program still does work if it just doesn't convert the output to those strings.

Comment: I think that byte bonuses to offset the byte size of text is totally fine.  It's not one of those "Bonus X points if you also do this other task".  The challenge is centered around the seasons, so it makes sense to 
incentivize actually printing the seasons.

Comment: The bonus feels silly, because the season names are 24 bytes of data, so most languages will not break even. For example, the 60-byte C answer which aims for the bonus could just be `f(m,a){return a&1?++a+m/3&3:2*!!a;}` for 35 bytes.

Comment: @Lynn Perhaps I should change it to -24 bonus then? Or maybe 33% bonus?

Comment: I think you should remove it :)

Comment: @Lynn Sorry, but I won't. I initially posted this challenge enforcing the output of the season-strings for everyone, but _ErikTheOutgolfer_ wasn't happy with it, so I eventually allowed any four distinct outputs and added the bonus as compromise. As _NathanMerrill_ mentioned, the challenge is focused about the seasons, so I wanted to somehow enforce actually outputting the seasons. A bonus seemed like a nice way to enforce it somewhat, although most non-golfing languages without built-in libraries/encoding will probably not benefit from it.

Answer (score 10):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>33 27</s> 25 bytes

```ruby
->m,l{[6,m,0,m+6][l]/3%4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5XJ6c62kwnV8dAJ1fbLDY6J1bfWNWk9r@GrpGenpGmXm5iQXVNRY2GoZ6eIYxbWVOgEB1doVMZq6OQFl2pUxEbW1v7HwA)

Return values are:

0 -> winter

1 -> spring

2 -> summer

3 -> autumn

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda p,m:[0,m+6,6,m][p]/3%4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5BDoIwEIXhtZxiNqY0DrEdDCEkngRYYLTaxJaGsPH0FUvE2bn@58ub8Jofo6dozl18Du5yHSCga1qF7lBhha5vQ38s96cYJutnEAVBDd0sEMDkBWEts1/RtKZUNG1JbWZJihm1kRQYIU74DHGyrmRmnMCC9TAN/n7LNepSNtnu@5gWaFF8zPKYRiv/AH6fzuMb)

A port of [G B's Ruby approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164757/76162), which turned out to be a few bytes shorter than my own:

#### 32 bytes

```python
lambda p,m:(p%2*(p+m/3+5)or p)%4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5BDsIgEIXhtT3FbBrATiNMNWmaeJNuMIqSCCWkG0@PtY3IzvU/X@aF1/yYPCVzHtNTu8tVQ0A38FDTnofGHbrmJKYIQdTHFKL1M7CWoIdxZghgeEvYi@pXFG1pLYpyktksSRZGZrKGglBJyjdUku1LZZaRFqyHqP39xhWqTgzV7jtMMbTIPmYZptCKP6C8X8/TGw)

An anonymous function that returns the seasons as the numbers 0 to 3, where they represent Summer, Autumn, Winter and Spring in that order.

As for printing the actual season names:

#### 63 - 15 = 48 bytes

```python
lambda p,m:"SAWSuuipmtnrmutiemenrnrg"[(p%2*(p+m/3+5)or p)%4::4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc6xDoIwFIXhWZ7ihoS0lRJpwYQ0cfAZGBzUASNgE1uapgw@fUWI2M35v1/uMS/3GDT33eHin4263RswVIm4Pp7qcZRGOW3V6GSrWm217eMzNgnfYpOqXZHuyWDBkKQUorx6Y6V2gDIOFVwcogAdzjitSPQrjC9pLoyvKV/NlPLA5CuZQ0B4SMI3PCTLl6ibhkqQGmyj@xYzygoios13GENUUvQx0zBGJfkDwvv53L8B)

There's the combined string if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>78</strike> 75 (-15 bonus) = 60 bytes

Using 1-based months.

*Edit:* Rearranged mathematical operators and reduced.

```c
f(m,a){puts("Summer\0Autumn\0Winter\0Spring"+7*(a*a&1?(++a+m/3)%4:2*!!a));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxLDoIwAET3nKJgNP2AApoYP8F4BhYuhEUtvya0EGjZEM5ey8q4e29mMiyoGTMbLlmrixLcR1Xwbt8kzl/U8o/NTAWFT9HcazVCL9VClEMWPrXSQmbhi0u1etoPXNYeOWNIMd1FD0gIJeJwRNvTNcauSxG6LcaugaBcwhXoUDOfNXQAGFueEJgdAHgF1yKJEbCkOr7q9I5y5P8szu2dsxhzMUH0BQ)

Comment: You can save two bytes with `(++a+m/3)%4` → `++a+m/3&3`. Also, `a*a` is odd precisely when `a` is, so checking `a&1` should be fine, no?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 26 - 15 = 11 bytes

Uses the approach found by [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164757/47066)

```
6¹¾¹6+)sè3÷4%“–„Ž¹Ž€È±“#sè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7NDOQ/sO7TTT1iw@vML48HYT1UcNcx41TH7UMO/o3kM7j@591LTmcMehjUBRZaCK//9NuHQNAQ)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##AVQAq/8wNWFiMWX/Migyxbh2MTJGTj5V/zZYwr5YNispecOoM8O3NCXigJzigJPigJ7FvcK5xb3igqzDiMKx4oCcI3PDqP9YeSLDvywgw78gLT4gw78iLP8)